# Why is this while-loop not working?

Tags: java, while-loop

The following code compiles, but when I ran it, it didn't enter the while-loop. Why ?

```
while (Str1.equals(Str2)); {
    count = 1;
    while (count <= maxCount); {
        System.out.print(something1);
        count = count + 1; } }
```

Comment: Because it's not `javascript`

Comment: Take the semi-colen off the back `while (Str1.equals(Str2)){}`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semi colon, semicolon is added only for do-while.Here is your code:

```
while (Str1.equals(Str2))
{
  count = 1;
  while (count <= maxCount) 
  {
     System.out.print(something1);
     count = count + 1; 
   }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! That fixed it.